# Which quartz.org is compatible with JDK 11.0.20

Tags: quartz

I am facing this error in log, I feel the quartz need to be updates it's currently in 2.2.3

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at deployment.nms8770-   scheduler.sar//org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:77)
at deployment.nms8770-     scheduler.sar//org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:105)
at deployment.nms8770-    scheduler.sar//org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1115)
at deployment.nms8770-scheduler.sar//org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1373)
at deployment.nms8770-scheduler.sar//org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1832)
at deployment.nms8770-scheduler.sar//org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1590)
at deployment.nms8770-scheduler.sar//org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:995)
at deployment.nms8770-scheduler.sar//org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:397)
at deployment.nms8770-scheduler.sar//org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
at deployment.nms8770-scheduler.sar//org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
at deployment.nms8770-scheduler.sar//org.apache.axis2.transport.http.impl.httpclient3.HTTPSenderImpl.executeMethod(HTTPSenderImpl.java:872)
at deployment.nms8770-scheduler.sar//org.apache.axis2.transport.http.impl.httpclient3.HTTPSenderImpl.sendViaPost(HTTPSenderImpl.java:212)
```

Scheduled export is a feature present in our product but upon initiating the process the above error occur

Comment: You feel that Quartz should be updated but you don't say why. However the latest version of Quartz Is 2.3.2, why don't you give it a try?

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example. Without it no one test and understand fully your question.